# Rubyのフレームワークについて教えてください

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

失礼します。
RubyのウェブアプリケーションフレームワークでRails以外で実際に使われているメジャーなものを教えてください。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 「フレームワーク」とは、Webアプリケーションフレームワークのことを指していますか？（単にフレームワークと指すとそれ以外のものを指します） / 「実際に使われている」や「メジャーなもの」という表現もかなり曖昧です。

Answer (score 3):

Railsが挙げられているため、Webアプリケーションを指しているものとして一旦回答します（違ったらこの回答を削除します）。

[Web Framework Benchmarks](https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/)という、様々な言語で作られた様々なWebアプリケーションフレームワークの性能を比較するサイトがあります。このサイトに掲載されていることを **メジャーである** として、以下に列挙してみます。

また、このサイトには掲載されていませんが、HanamiというWebアプリケーションフレームワークもある程度存在感があるので、合わせて掲載します。

なお、今回は以下のRound 17でSingle Queryという簡単なクエリが実行できるもののみを選択しています。
https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r17&hw=ph&test=db&l=zijxtr-1

## Sinatra

Railsがデータベースとの連携のような機能をすべて兼ね備えている（フルスタックフレームワークと呼ばれる）のと対象的に、Webアプリケーションフレームワークとしての機能のみを持っている（マイクロフレームワークと呼ばれる）。個人的には、Railsの次に知名度が高いように思います。

- [Sinatra](http://sinatrarb.com/)

  - 公式
- [Sinatra: README (Japanese)](http://sinatrarb.com/intro-ja.html)

  - 公式日本語訳
- [GitHub - sinatra/sinatra: Classy web-development dressed in a DSL (official / canonical repo)](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra)

  - GitHub
- [Sinatra - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinatra)

  - Wikipedia

## Padrino

Sinatraをベースに、MVCなどの機能を持たせたもの。

- [Padrino - The Elegant Ruby Web Framework](http://padrinorb.com/)

  - 公式
- [GitHub - padrino/padrino-framework: Padrino is a full-stack ruby framework built upon Sinatra.](https://github.com/padrino/padrino-framework)

  - GitHub
- [Padrino - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padrino)

  - Wikipedia

## Grape

REST風APIを構築するために設計されたフレームワーク。もちろん通常のWebサイトも作成できる。

- [GitHub - ruby-grape/grape: An opinionated framework for creating REST-like APIs in Ruby.](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape)

  - GitHub

## Roda

「ルーティングツリーWebツールキット」と呼ばれる、ルーティングに基づく設計に主眼をおいたもの。

- [GitHub - jeremyevans/roda: Routing Tree Web Toolkit](https://github.com/jeremyevans/roda)

  - GitHub
- [Ruby: 高速/高性能ルーティングエンジンgem「Roda」README: 前編（翻訳）](https://techracho.bpsinc.jp/hachi8833/2018_05_08/55845)

  - 解説記事

## Hanami

Railsの不満点を解消するために作られた、フルスタックフレームワークをシンプルに設計するためのフレームワーク。2017年の桜の時期にv1.0.0がリリースされたようです。

- [Hanami | The web, with simplicity](https://hanamirb.org/)

  - 公式
- [GitHub - hanami/hanami: The web, with simplicity.](https://github.com/hanami/hanami)

  - GitHub
- [HanamiはRubyの救世主(メシア)となるか、愚かな星と散るのか](https://magazine.rubyist.net/articles/0056/0056-hanami.html)

  - 紹介記事

Comment: 上の方でご親切に案内してくださったみな様、回答を寄せてくださったPicoSushiさま、どうもありがとうございます！知りたかったことを回答していただきました！ありがとうございます。これからもよろしくお願いします♪

Comment: @東ハラミ さん、解決してよかったです。[回答を承認](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)することもできますので、よければご検討くださいませ。